# Maven inside docker container horribly slow

Tags: macos, performance, maven, docker

I'm trying to setup a Docker container to build my java project with maven

I have created my Docker file FROM maven:3.2-jdk-7 and built the image.

when I execute with:

> docker run -it --rm --name my-maven-project -v "$PWD":/usr/src/app -v
>   "$HOME"/.m2:/root/.m2 -w /usr/src/app -v "$HOME"/.ssh:/root/.ssh  test
>   mvn clean package -Dmaven.test.skip=true

**It takes about 20 minute to complete.. but if I run the the same mvn command on my host it takes 2minutes**

I have tried giving more memory to the container by using

> -m 4gb

But it didn't change anything, looking at docker stats the container barely used more than 2G

I'm running all this from OSX

Is there anything I need to do to have a maven finish in a decent time? I very very surprised it takes THAT much when on the host it takes 2minutes..

This what docker stats says after maven has been building for 10 min

```
CPU: 201.13% 
Mem usage  / limit : 2.508GiB
 MEM %  : 62.69%
NET I/O: 3.01kB / 861B
BLOCK I/O: 57.7MB / 2.23MB
PIDS: 38
```

***- EDIT -***
It turns out Docker for mac does not play well when using mounted volume. 
In order to avoid having to git clone the project inside the container I preferred using using -v "$PWD":/usr/src/app

To test I have directly git cloned the app form within the container and now the build takes a normal amount of time (4minutes)

Note that the git clone took... 6 min!!! instead (1min on host) so in total from git clone to final build it still takes 10min which is ridiculous.

So yea OSX and Docker is a big no no when using mounted volume...

Comment: Well, it depends... the first build will be slower, until Maven has downloaded all the dependencies from the remote repository. After that, unless you rebuild the instance, it should be okay. Have you tried it more than once? :)

Comment: Yes as you can see I'm mounting the host volume (.m2) which already has all the depenecies. So maven in the container doesn't need to to download anything

Comment: Are you running a current version of docker? It's had some problems with filesystem performance on OS X.

Comment: What's the output...? is this happening when downloading dependencies, or...?

Comment: I'm running Version 17.06.0-ce-mac19 (18663) updating to 17.09.0-ce-mac35 (19611) did not fix the issue. Build on container still takes 20min

Comment: Running a Maven build inside a Docker container makes not really sense...Why not running plain on Mac Os ? Any advantage to run the build itself inside the docker container?

Comment: @khmarbaise doesn't make sense using docker at all then ;) we could do everything on host.... 
BUT since I'm in a good mood.. it does make when your app requires several dependencies to build and you don't want your QA to lose 3 hours setting their local to build a war :)

Comment: Why does a QA need to setup a build. Just build your application deploy it to a repository manager or if you build a docker image with your application deploy the docker image to a docker registry....? Furthermore what about a CI solution ?

Comment: Mounting some files with -v on mac can impact performance. Check out this for info how to improve it: https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/bind-mounts/#configure-mount-consistency-for-macos

Comment: @odk bingo. I have been mounting the source code repo with -v to avoid having to git clone in the container.. I have tried changing to that and the build finishes now in 3minute

Comment: But... the git clone takes a ridiculous amount of time(6min) instead of max 1 min on host

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm experiencing a similar issue: download speed within containers drops horribly slow after few seconds.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this same issue using the same docker run syntax as you (docker run -v src:dest). A Maven build that took ~30 seconds on my OSX host was taking ~4 minutes in my container. I didn't solve it entirely, but switching to explicitly use a bind mount took my builds from around 4 minutes down to about 1.5 minutes. This still isn't an acceptable increase in build time for my use case, but it may help someone else. Try switching your docker run command to this:

```
docker run --name=my-maven-project -it \ 
--mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)",destination=/usr/src/app,consistency=delegated <docker image name>
```

NOTE: The consistency option at the very end is only valid on OSX, and has two other values, either of which may be more appropriate for your situation. I tried all three out of curiosity and build times were comparable between the delegated and cached options, meanwhile the consistent option nearly as slow as the way I was doing it before (unsurprisingly). Here's the documentation:

https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/

So, unfortunately, despite bind mounts being "very performant," they're still apparently at least twice as slow as a native filesystem when it comes to maven builds, at least on OSX. With luck that will improve as time goes on.

Comment: I see the same but aren't mount's with "-v" bind mounts? maybe they weren't at the time of the post but the doc states:

> -v "$(pwd):/app" - bind mount the current directory from the host in the container into the /app directory 

docker seems rather slow to me to and its not just maven, terraform is super slow too, and it didn't use to be like so, but I'm unsure in which version this started.

Comment: 3 years after this answer and things are _worse_ than in 2019. We are seeing 100x worse performance in file intensive maven related work. :(